# how to uncompress an archive based on the file command

Tags: bash, shell-script

Im new to bash scripting, and I want to write a script called unpack, something like this:

```
unpack [-r] [-v] file [file...]
-v - verbose
-r - recursive - will traverse contents of folders recursively, performing unpack on each.
```

I need to determine what kind of compression was used and perform unpacking for those compression types.

Assuming file names and extensions could have no meaning - the only way to know what method to use is through the file command. I have 4 unpacking options gunzip, bunzip2, unzip, uncompress

so I wrote a function called execute_unpacking

```
#!/bin/bash

exectute_unpacking(){

    for FILE in "${@}"
    do
        local FILE_TYPE=$(file "${FILE}")

        # How to get the compression type of the file?

        case "${FILE_TYPE}" in
            *bzip2) bunzip2 ${RECURSIVE} "${FILE}" ;;
            *gzip) gunzip ${RECURSIVE} "${FILE}" ;;
            *Zip) unzip ${RECURSIVE} ${FILE} ;;
            *compress) uncomprees ${RECURSIVE} ${FILE} ;;
            ?) echo "${FILE} cannot be extarcted" ;;
        esac

    done
}
```

So based on the $(file ${FILE}) i need to check for Zip, bzip2, compress, gzip

Is this the correct way to do it? (i don't want to use external tools like dtrx )

For example if I have 4 files:

```
$(file -i archive) => archive: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
$(file -i archive.bz2) => archive.bz2: application/x-bzip2; charset=binary
$(file -i archvive.gz) =>archive.gz: application/x-gzip; charset=binary
$(file -i archive.cmpr) => archive.cmpr: application/x-compress; charset=binary
```

So i need to assign to the FILE_TYPE variable 4 options gzip,compress,bzip2,txt and then match those pattern accordingly inside of my case statement

When I tried to ./unpack.sh archive.zip Nothing happened unfortantelly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "_I don't want to use external tools like dtrx_" you're already using external tools like `bzip2`, `gunzip`, `uncompress`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
local file_type=$(file -b "${FILE}" | awk '{print $1}')
```

You can then test for XZ, gzip, etc or whatever it produces.

Answer (score 0):

Just use libarchive `bsdtar`, which can extract most archive formats (`tar`, `tgz`, `zip`, `iso`s...) by itself:

```
bsdtar -xf "$any_archive"
```

(see also additional options such as `p`/`o`/`S` to handle permissions, ownership, sparseness where relevant).

Or libarchive's `bsdcat` to uncompress most compression formats (`gz`, `xz`, `bz2`)

```
bsdcat -- "$compressed_file" > "$uncompressed_file"
```

Note that `zip` is an archive format, not (only) a compression format. `zip` archives will typically contain more than one member. `bsdcat` would just concatenate them. Use `bsdtar` instead to extract them.